# Parsing GPS Coordinates Python coming from TCP/IP connection

Tags: database, parsing, tcp, gps, coordinates

So I'm currently connecting to a local Linux TCP Server over 8888 and sending GPS coordinates and temperature readings from my Arduino shield Quectel BG96 modem.

After that, I then send the received data to a mySQL Database as Temperature and Location columns respectively.

The Thing is that my location coordinates are mixed (UTC time, long and lat are all in the one string) and I want to be able to separate them before I send them to the Database (Ill add extra columns for this)

I would appreciate any assistance in researching the most efficient way to separate/parse the strings.

My Socket Server Python Script

```
        while True:
        data = connection.recv()
        print >>sys.stderr, 'received "%s"' % data
    print(len(data))
        if (len(data) < 15):
    temp = data
    else:
    Loc = data
    try: 

        
        now=datetime.datetime.utcnow()
        print(now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
        #Datain = """INSERT INTO irthermo(temperature, location, TIME) VALUES (%s, %s,%s)""",(temp,Loc,now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
                    Datain = "INSERT INTO irthermo(temperature, location, TIME) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)"
        values= (temp,Loc,now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))   
        cursor.execute(Datain,values)
        con.commit()
        print(cursor.rowcount, "Hello")
    except Error as e:
        print("Error while connecting to Mysql", e)
         

        
finally:
if (con.is_connected()):
    con.close()
    print("connection closed")
    cursor.close()
    # Clean up the connection
    connection.close()
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question (and possibly you do not know exactly where the problem is). If you have problem on interpreting the data, maybe you should ask to our sister site "arduino" (you get the list on top right icon, in this site). It is ugly to distinguish the data type using the length of the data. When you have a understanding of the data format, the programming part (which is ok in this site) should be easier.

Comment: My issue is taking Loc variable and splinting it to separate Longitude Latitude etc so I can send it to MySQL database respectively.[because now its jst a huge string even with information i dont need like 3D Fix  - Altitute etc]... I know how the format of the GPS coord is, I can even see it displayed in terminal, no issue here. 

Maybe answering my own question, but I think just splitting the Loc string using the split function maybe and storing into array, then adding arrays to make the format of (5522.343,N) and (734573.34E) for example

Comment: BTW `print >>sys.stderr, 'received "%s"' % data` seems copied from C++. (and you should edit your question, to make ident better (it matter in python) The ugly part is how you get the data (and you get just a part, but you save also the other part). Edit your question, and add what you get, and what you want (we do not know the format of your database): a string, two numbers (negative for S and W?), etc.

Comment: The usual tools: `split()`, or just slices (`[x:y]`), or regexp (you know the format of coordinate, and that they finish with a letter NWSE) are the most used tools. Else one needs to implement own parser. But you should check on ardiuno part to put the data in a simple way (e.g. coma separated values, a letter to distinguish fields, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

[Image of MyPHPAdmin showing the Database values coming inr LAT and LONG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/agPKS.png)I managed to make something like this which is working for me now:

```
        print(len(data))
        if (len(data) < 15) :
    if ">" in data.strip():
        temp = data
        temp1 = temp.split(">")
        print(temp1[1])
    else:
    Loc = data
    try: 
        loc1 = Loc.split(": ")
        loc2 = loc1[1]
        # setting the maxsplit parameter to 1, will return a list with 2 elements!
        loc3 = loc2.split(",")
        if len(loc3) >= 4 :
            LAT=loc3[1]+loc3[2]
            LONG=loc3[3]+loc3[4]
            now=datetime.datetime.utcnow()
            print(now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
            #Datain = """INSERT INTO irthermo(temperature, location, TIME) VALUES (%s, %s,%s)""",(temp,Loc,now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
                        Datain = "INSERT INTO irthermo(temperature, Lat, Lon, TIME) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s)"
            values= (temp1[1],LAT,LONG,now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))   
            cursor.execute(Datain,values)
            con.commit()
        else:
                LAT=loc3[1]+loc3[2]
            LONG="Unknown"
            now=datetime.datetime.utcnow()
            print(now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
            #Datain = """INSERT INTO irthermo(temperature, location, TIME) VALUES (%s, %s,%s)""",(temp,Loc,now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
                        Datain = "INSERT INTO irthermo(temperature, Lat, Lon, TIME) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s)"
            values= (temp1[1],LAT,LONG,now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))   
            cursor.execute(Datain,values)
            con.commit()
    except Error as e:
        print("Error transfer Data", e)
```